# Mass Effect 3. Can I have one version for multiplayer and another for single player?

Tags: mass-effect-3, technical-issues

I currently have an original version of mass effect 3, which I bought just for the multi-player. However, I also already have another version of mass effect 3 that installed that I use solely for single player. This single player version contains all the dlc's and extras weapons and so-forth that come with mass effect 3 pre-orders etc.

My question is: Will my multiplayer-earned galatic readiness score still affect these saves I have on my single player version of the game? Will the single-player saves even load on the multiplayer version on the game ( Because the multiplayer version is merely the default version of Mass effect 3, without the extra weapons/armours, useslly battery dog etc. )

Much thanks if anyone could get back to me with answers to my queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Galatic Readiness is bound up on you Origin account, so as long as they are the same, you should be fine.

At least it seems to work that way, since the ME3 Datapad only needs an Origin login to work.

Comment: Somehow I doubt the "single player" version signs into Origin.

Comment: If you have ANY DLC the single player does sign into origin. See: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54050/can-i-use-mass-effect-3-dlc-while-offline

Comment: So this means that if I don't log onto origin on my single player-version, and stay online, I can't get the Galatic readiness that I'll have earned from multiplayer onto that single-player version?      So this means that Galactic Readiness is thus bound to the origin account, and only by logging onto the origin account, your save games will get the affiliated earned Galactic Readiness?