# Can I play the new Mass Effect 3 ending with an offline profile?

Tags: mass-effect-3, xbox-360

I beat Mass Effect 3 for Xbox 360 using my offline (i.e. not Xbox live) profile. For some reason I always use that for my gaming. I've downloaded the Extended Cut DLC using Xbox live, but want to play it with my offline account.

There is no indication whether the DLC has loaded. I don't exactly want to play for 3 hours from the Legend save point only to find the same, worst ending ever.

Do I have to restart?

This previous question is about previous DLC, and for the PC.
[Can I use Mass Effect 3 DLC while offline?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54050/can-i-use-mass-effect-3-dlc-while-offline)

If I don't get an answer I guess I'll play it through and let all you Xbox 360 offline players (all 3 of us) know.

Comment: You can always turn down the difficult to "Narrative" mode, so it won't take you as long to get through the fights. https://twitter.com/manveerheir/status/217615752021295104

Comment: @Mufasa Yes, this is what I did. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No I'm pretty sure you don't, it shouldnt matter if it's online or not as long as you have the DLC downloaded.

PS. The DLC is so much better than the original.

Comment: Correct. The crappy new ending is available offline.

Comment: @Alex "Much better" is an opinion rather than a fact - just sayin' :)

Answer (score 0):

no! it doesn't work!  if you beat the game in an offline profile and downloaded the DLC on a different online profile, the DLC DOES NOT freaking work in your offline profile.  I just wasted hours of my life.  I went back and played from the save created when you beat the game all the way through to the end

Comment: I don't know. Worked for me. I beat the game with my offline profile. Downloaded DLC with my online profile. Played through with my offline profile from my legend save point and got the new "improved" ending.