# Origin: Online login is unavailable? Can I still play?

Tags: mass-effect-3, origin

I always login into Origin in online mode. But today for past two hours or so (since I got home) Origin says "Origin: Online login is unavailable" when I fire up my client.

It does give me access in Offline mode. But when I launch ME3, all of EA's servers are offline, so can not resume my saved game since it depends on Omega, From Ashes, and Leviathan.

Is it possible to play any game and in particular ME3 with Origin servers offline in this fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the game. As you have found out, Mass Effect 3 requires online authorization for all DLC (but not for the base game, so they can claim to not require online mode while effectively crippling the game in offline mode), so you cannot load a save that has DLC data (basically any save that was made in online mode if you have ME3 DLC). You can start a new ME3 game without DLC in offline mode, but it will get DLC data written to it once you load it and make a save in online mode.

Comment: I've definitely played ME3 with DLC both online and offline on the same save file without problem.

Comment: @Kareen in that case you're the exception http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54050/can-i-use-mass-effect-3-dlc-while-offline

Comment: I just tried it again to confirm, and sure enough, I can resume my save file with DLC data while in offline mode and play the DLC. Guess I'll count my blessings.

Comment: @Vaishali EA is taking incompetence and/or evil to new heights.